# how to upload mulitiple file with expressjs?

Tags: forms, node.js, file-upload, express

this is my html

```
<form action="/keys/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<ul>
        <li><label>文件</label><input type="file" name="keys" multiple></li>
        <li><input type="submit" value="submit"></li>
</ul>
</form>
```

this is my handle function

```
app.post('/keys/upload',keysRoutes.addKeys);

var addKeys=function(req,res){
    var temppaths=req.files.keys[0].path;
    console.log(temppaths);
    res.end(JSON.stringify(temppaths));
};
```

here if i upload more than one file,then `req.files.keys[0].path` works fine,but when i only upload one file,it goes wrong,i have to replace it as `req.files.keys.path`. i don,t know how many files will be upload,so what should i do?

sometimes req.files.keys is array,sometimes req.files.keys is object.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you should check if it's an array or an object; when it's not an array, wrap it into one:

```
var paths = req.files.keys || [];

if (! (paths instanceof Array) ) {
  paths = [ paths ];
}
```

Comment: Oh,thank you,i'm seeking for a method to judge if a object is an array,the method you give is concise,and the method Object.prototype.toString.call(paths)=='[object Array]' is so tedious.

Comment: Another one could be `paths.constructor.name === 'Array'`.

Answer (score 0):

I find a method,I think I can use

```
var paths=[].concat(paths);
```

then paths will always be an array